# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable g.user.is_authenticated()

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to do this in my Flask application. But I am getting an error like this

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.
```

Here is the corresponding code:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    if g.user.is_authenticated():
       g.search_form = None
```

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try replace `if g.user.is_authenticated():` to `if g.user.is_authenticated:` like this:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    if g.user.is_authenticated:
       g.search_form = None
```

From [the document](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class):

> **is_authenticated**
>
> Returns True if the user is authenticated, i.e. they have provided valid credentials. (Only authenticated users will fulfill the criteria of login_required.)

As the document said, **is_authenticated** is a boolean(`True` or `False`).

And however, **it was a function in the past**, [but it has been changed to boolean at version 3.0](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/CHANGES#L30):

> **BREAKING:**
>   The `is_authenticated`, `is_active`, and `is_anonymous`
>   members of the user class are now properties, not methods. Applications should update
>     their user classes accordingly.

Comment: I had the same issue with django. Calling "is_authenticated" as a property instead of as a method resolved it. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 6):

This is because `is_authenticated` is not a function but a mere boolean. Try the following instead:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    if g.user.is_authenticated:
       g.search_form = None
```